# svn + ssh and redirect ssh port

Tags: svn, router, ports

i have a problem with the access to my repository, i explain:

i have a server: "andromeda" with my repository of svn, in my local net i have 2 pc's: "andromeda" and "mine", with "mine" i connect succesful to svn+ssh://192.168.1.10/var/svn/blablabla but i want to access it outside my net, i have an static ip like this: 80.21.152.xxx, i have redirect the ports 80 and 22 to 192.168.1.10 configured in my router. but the problem is that i cant connect in local to svn+ssh://80.21.152.xxx, i think that the router believe that this ssh connection is for him and not redirect (only when i do from local net), how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i didn't make this, only good routers without nat can redirect correctly in this cases, or maybe if you have a dns server in your net. Thus i use 2 different ip's in etc/hosts